# How to simulate hedging position with cumprod with python correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, yahoo-finance

I was trying to simulate a hedging position using a single stock on python

```
import yfinance as yf

#getting the data

data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2021-01-01", end="2022-01-01")

#calculating returns
data['Returns'] = data['Close'].pct_change()

#simulating investing 1000$ on the stock
((data['Returns']+1).cumprod() * 1000).plot()

#simulating shorting 1000$ on the stock
((data['Returns']*-1+1).cumprod() * 1000).plot()
```

Everything looks right, however, if you sum both of the positions, they do not cancel each other and the portfolio varies over time instead of staying always at 2000$.

```
(((data['Returns']+1).cumprod() * 1000) + ((data['Returns']*-1+1).cumprod() * 1000)).plot()
```

[image: As you can see]

If I'm opening opposite positions, they should cancel each other out and the total value of the portfolio should stay at 2000$ during the entire period, as the profits of one position, will be the losses on the other position and vice-versa.

I believe its a problem with the `.cumprod()` function, but how can solve this to have a fully neutral position?

Comment: maybe first get very small set of data - so you could calculate it on paper and compare with result in code. Use `print()` to see what you get in code in every step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you "sell" $1000 instead.  So the hedged should be exactly the same as the long position, using 1+pct_change, but with -$1000.  This way the overall portfolio is $0 throughout, i.e. 100% hedged.

```
(((data['Returns']+1).cumprod() * 1000) + ((data['Returns']+1).cumprod() * -1000)).plot()
```

This is required because you need the same percentage movements in the opposite direction.  By subtracting the same nominal percentage change from 1 you will not receive the same result after the second multiplication.

Numerically: `50 * (1-0.05) = 47.5` and `50 * (1+0.05) = 52.5`, but `47.5 * 0.05` and `52.5 * 0.05` are not going to be equal so `47.5*(1-0.05) != 52.5*(1+0.05)`.  For this reason, you need to work with a positive $1000 and a negative $1000 to perfectly offset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).